# Rename generated Next.js static files

Tags: next.js

I have a page, doma.in/analytics. NextJS generates a static file named as the path (analytics) + etag: `https://doma.in/_next/static/chunks/pages/analytics-c9463hj2394r83k4.js`. The problem is, AdBlock is blocking the file because of the `analytics` string in the filename.

Is it possible to rename it somehow?

Comment: You could mess around with a [custom webpack config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config) yourself, or just change the name of the page for a simpler solution.